# IRS2153(1) half bridge giving irregular output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm following standard design recommendations for a IRS2153(1) half bridge driver in the following setup:
[image: schematic]
The problem is that the output (measured at the joining net of Q1, Q2, L1, pin 6 and C3 negative relative to ground)  is unstable (it should be a steady pulse train, the horizontal scale is 200 ms to show that the irregularity appears at larger timescales: the resulting bursts in between are with the intended frequency): [image: irregular output - teal is LO (pin 5), yellow is HO (pin 7)]
It seems to be a saw-tooth like behaviour with a moving time base. I've tried many configurations (different input voltage, C1, R2, C2 and C3 combinations, together with replacing L choke with a R and skipping the potential divider C4 C5 with connecting the L straight to ground). Does anybody have similar experience with this IC? I've tried the IRS2153 too with a bootstrap diode and it still has a beat freuqency.

**SOLVED:** IC pin 1 needs at least 20 mA to function properly, a 56k resistor provides too little current. Around 12k 10W works for the given configuration.

Comment: Quick observation - datasheet says max supply current 20mA, but R1 won't allow it to have more than about 5mA before Vcc drops to zero.

Comment: Will try! It is the only value I have not played around with. I have shared the thought.

Comment: @Finbarr - that solved it! 12k 10W seems OK for the job :) Thank you!

Comment: Accept your own answer so that the site can recognize the question as answered.  If you don't accept an answer, it will continue to pop up on the questions page as an unanaswered question and people will wonder why you abandoned it.

Comment: The thing is that you try to refuel a 10-uF bootstrap capacitor (unless there is a typo) whereas the common value for this cap. is 100 nF or so. Everytime the low-side SW closes, you connect this uncharged capacitor to the circuit Vcc so no wonder it drops and forces a hiccup mode. Besides reducing the 56-k resistor, did you try to reduce the booststrap cap. value as well? The consumption mainly comes from the MOSFET \$Q_G\$ (around 8 mA each with a 120-kHz \$F_{sw}\$ and a 65-nC \$Q_G\$). I would personally add a 12-V Zener from \$V_{cc}\$ to GND so that the internal Zener is never activated.

Answer (score 2):

IC pin 1 needs at least 20 mA to function properly, a 56k resistor provides too little current. Around 12k 10W works for the given configuration. Thanks @Finbarr.

Comment: It's a lot of power being converted into heat, so make sure you get rid of it somehow even if the resistor power rating is sufficient. Do you not have a lower voltage supply in your design that you can use?

Comment: A lower voltage is not available for this design iteration - it is a matter of cost and time.